# Reorganize a FileList JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I am pretty new to front-end development and I am trying to do something pretty unique without much luck. What I want to do is be able to take a list of files from the FileList and be able to specify one file for the user to use as a base or seed file.

So pretty much I have an input that allows the user to select the files they need then I want to figure out another way for the user to select the base file they want and then when it is uploaded to the server that file will be uploaded FIRST.

Some code I use for upload:

```
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', '$log',
    function ($http, $log) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
            //$log.debug("file(s)");
            //$log.debug(file);
            var fd = new FormData();
            angular.forEach(file, function (value, key) {
                fd.append(key, value);
            });
            return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined,
                    'enctype': "multipart/form-data"
                }
            })
        }; // uploadFileToUrl
    }]); // fileUpload
```

Now I have been told this might be difficult because FileLists are immutable but I am open to other suggestions that do not change the current structure.